# Access MenuItem programmatically to change Textcolor

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

When User click on the item in the menu the `onOptionsItemSelected` fires passing `MenuItem` as an argument. this passed `MenuItem` extends the `TextView` and not the same that we can get from `menu.findItem()` method. 
To access this user needs to click on the item, I want to access this Object without user clicking on the item in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

in On resume just call findViewById and cast it to TextView. 
You need to make this in a Timer to postdelay your code until the view is rednered as this is rendered by menu. 
for me it works like this

```
  if (!created) { // for first resume only
        created = true;
        Timer t = new Timer();
           t.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Might be done in better way, dont  know yet
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while true {
                        final Object o = findViewById(R.id.mServerTime);
                        if (o == null) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (o != null && o instanceof TextView) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        ((TextView) o).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception exp) {}
            }
        },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments in the answer above, so I'm writing another answer. A more reliable way to know when the view is actually placed on the screen is observing it's ViewTreeObserver such as:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
    // Instance variables
    OnLayoutReadyListener onLayoutReadyListener = new OnLayoutReadyListener();
    View v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        v = findViewById(R.id.mServerTime);
        v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onLayoutReadyListener);
    }

    class OnLayoutReadyListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // this will be called once view V is placed and measured on the screen
            v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            // remove this listener to prevent any additional callbacks
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onLayoutReadyListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: v = findViewById(R.id.mServerTime); will return null in the onCreate.